# Rollup nested subdocuments to do aggregate query

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have documents stored like this:

```
{
  _id: 1001,
  name: "pointa"
  data: [
    {
      dataid: 123,
      parentid: 44,
      count: 12
    },
    {
      dataid: 234,
      parentid: 45,
      count: 5
    }
  ],
  subPoints: {
    pointa_a: {
      name: "pointa_a",
      data: [
        {
          dataid: 123,
          parentid: 44,
          count: 4
        },
        {
          dataid: 234,
          parentid: 45,
          count: 5
        }
      ]
    },
    pointa_b: {
      name: "pointa_b",
      data: [
        {
          dataid: 123,
          parentid: 44,
          count: 8
        },
      ]
    },
  }
},
// 'pointb' has no subpoints
{
  _id: 1001,
  name: "pointb"
  data: [
    {
      dataid: 123,
      parentid: 44,
      count: 3
    },
    {
      dataid: 234,
      parentid: 45,
      count: 25
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to be able to get the count of "data" grouped either by the `dataid` or the `parentid`. And my query might be something like for all pointa_b and all of pointb, so it could be the root or, it could be for nested documents combined.  I tried to use unwind to bring up all of the data for the sub-points to the root level, but then if a document doesn't have that particular sub-point, it doesn't show up in the result.

For example if I do:

```
db.test1.aggregate([
  {$unwind : "$data"},
  {$unwind : "$subPoints.pointa_b.data"}
]);
```

Then the data for "pointb" is missing.  If I could have all of the data for all of them at the root level then I know that I could use `$cond` to do a `$project` to pull out the data that I need.  Or even if I didn't have the root level data for the documents that have subPoints, I can sum up the data from the subPoints since it adds up to the parent, but I don't know how to flatten it like this.

Is there a way to un-nest subdocuments that have the same structure of the parent?

Comment: Are the subpoint keys like `pointa_b` named based on the `name` of the point, as the data suggests?

Comment: @wdberkeley yes, the subpoint keys are the same as the `name` of the point